# What is the order of install using Linux ver ?, Python ver ? , Kinectic and C ? newbee

Tags: ros

[image: Rosanswers logo]

The computer will talk to ros bot by RF and will be built with the best computer hardware for the AMD OR Intel , what would the best video card or 2 or 3 and how much memory  should I use on the desktop ??? the newbee

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/275827/what-is-the-order-of-install-using-linux-ver-?,-python-ver-?-,-kinectic-and-c-?-newbee/) by [westglade](https://answers.ros.org/users/32614/westglade/) on ROS Answers with karma: 1 on 2017-11-14

Post score: 0

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [ahendrix](https://answers.ros.org/users/1034/ahendrix/) on 2017-11-14**:
I don't really understand the question. Are you asking about software installation order or are you asking for hardware advice?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

There aren't really any real special system requirements to run ROS applications.

Any recent computer (ie: recent Intel or AMD processor, 4 cores, 4 to 8 GB of ram) should do for basic stuff.

A decent video card is also recommended, as otherwise you won't be able to comfortably use RViz, Gazebo or other graphical tools.

However, if you are looking to include 'heavy' processing in your application (ie: several lidars, multiple depth sensors, large maps (ie: high resolution) for navigation, large nr of concurrently active nodes) then these 'minimum requirements' (which I just made up, so are in no way official) start to increase.

More cores increase parallelism. Better graphic card handles large volumetric data sets better (ie: pointclouds, octomaps). More memory will reduce use of swap space and will allow you to work with larger data sets in-memory (deap learning fi).

But this all depends on what you actually want to do: a basic ROS application can run on things as low as a RPi (and even smaller systems).

---

Originally posted by [gvdhoorn](https://answers.ros.org/users/5184/gvdhoorn/) with karma: 86574 on 2017-11-14

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0